# Assert equals between 2 Lists in Junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, collections, junit

How can I make an equality assertion between lists in a ***JUnit*** test case? Equality should be between the content of the list.

For example:

```
List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
List<String> numbers2 = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
List<String> numbers3 = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "four"); 

// numbers should be equal to numbers2
//numbers should not be equal to numbers3
```

Comment: I like to use `assertArrayEquals` nowadays. Use in combination with `List#toArray`.

Comment: @Thibstars - I'd upvote that as an answer.

Comment: `assertArrayEquals` requires you to get arrays from your lists. You can operate directly on the list using `assertIterableEquals`

Comment: `assertIterableEquals` available for jUnit5 @ThetaSinner

Answer (score 199):

*For junit4! This question deserves a new answer written for [junit5](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-assertions-third-party).*

I realise this answer is written a couple years after the question, probably this feature wasn't around then. But now, it's easy to just do this:

```
@Test
public void test_array_pass()
{
  List<String> actual = Arrays.asList("fee", "fi", "foe");
  List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("fee", "fi", "foe");

  assertThat(actual, is(expected));
  assertThat(actual, is(not(expected)));
}
```

If you have a recent version of Junit installed with hamcrest, just add these imports:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
```

[http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat(T, org.hamcrest.Matcher)](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat%28T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher%29)

http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html

http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/hamcrest/core/Is.html

Comment: `System.out.println(actual == expected);` will return false, but `System.out.println(actual.equals(expected));` will return true.

Comment: @Catfish yeah, that's confusing isn't it. I think I was demonstrating that the matcher is using `.equals(..)` instead of `==`?

Comment: How is that better than assertEquals?

Comment: @Raedwald the output when the assertion fails. i'll try to come back later to edit in the difference. hamcrest matchers can generate detailed failure messages. it's possible for junit to simply overload assertEquals with similar goodness. but mostly junit provides core unit test features, and hamcrest provides a nice-to-have object difference describer library.

Comment: @djeikyb, `Assert.assertEquals` works right and outputs expected and actual lists when comparison fails.

Answer (score 66):

### For JUnit 5

you can use [`assertIterableEquals`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertIterableEquals-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Iterable-) :

```
List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
List<String> numbers2 = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");

Assertions.assertIterableEquals(numbers, numbers2);
```

or [`assertArrayEquals`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertArrayEquals-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object:A-) and converting lists to arrays :

```
List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
List<String> numbers2 = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
Assertions.assertArrayEquals(numbers.toArray(), numbers2.toArray());
```

Comment: Much simpler to upgrade to JUnit5. [Migration Instructions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-gradle-engines-configure) 

From: `testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13")` To: `testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0")
`

Answer (score 30):

Don't transform to string and compare. This is not good for perfomance. 
In the junit, inside Corematchers, there's a matcher for this => `hasItems`

```
List<Integer> yourList = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4)    
assertThat(yourList, CoreMatchers.hasItems(1,2,3,4,5));
```

This is the better way that I know of to check elements in a list.

Comment: Should be the chosen answer, with one note: You need also to verify that there are no more items in the list besides what you want. Maybe use:`Assert.assertEquals(4,yourList.size());`

Comment: or with a single line: `assertThat(yourList.toArray(), arrayContainingInAnyOrder(1,2,3,4,5));`

Comment: _"This is not good for perfomance."_ → I'm not sure to what degree one should take performance into account when writing _unit tests_... But sure, comparing strings via their `toString()` version is not the best way.

Answer (score 27):

`assertEquals(Object, Object)` from JUnit4/JUnit 5 or   `assertThat(actual, is(expected));` from Hamcrest proposed in the other answers will work only as both `equals()` and `toString()` are overrided for the classes (and deeply) of the compared objects.

It matters because the equality test in the assertion relies on `equals()` and the test failure message relies on `toString()` of the compared objects.
For built-in classes such as `String`, `Integer` and so for ... no problem as these override both `equals()` and `toString()`. So it is perfectly valid to assert `List<String>` or `List<Integer>` with  `assertEquals(Object,Object)`.
And about this matter : you have to override `equals()` in a class because it makes sense in terms of object equality, not only to make assertions easier in a test with JUnit.
To make assertions easier you have other ways.
As a good practice I favor assertion/matcher libraries.

Here is a [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) solution.

[`org.assertj.core.api.ListAssert.containsExactly()`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/ListAssert.html#containsExactly-ELEMENT...-) is what you need : it verifies that the actual group contains exactly the given values and nothing else, in order as stated in the javadoc.

Suppose a `Foo` class where you add elements and where you can get that.
A unit test of `Foo` that asserts that the two lists have the same content could look like :

```
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@Test
void add() throws Exception { 
   Foo foo = new Foo();
   foo.add("One", "Two", "Three");
   Assertions.assertThat(foo.getElements())
             .containsExactly("One", "Two", "Three");
}
```

A AssertJ good point is that declaring a `List` as expected is needless : it makes the assertion straighter and the code more readable :

```
Assertions.assertThat(foo.getElements())
         .containsExactly("One", "Two", "Three");
```

But Assertion/matcher libraries are a must because these will really further.
Suppose now that `Foo`  doesn't store `String`s but `Bar`s instances.
That is a very common need. 
With AssertJ the assertion is still simple to write. Better you can assert that the list content are equal even if the class of the elements doesn't override `equals()/hashCode()` while JUnit way requires that :

```
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import static org.assertj.core.groups.Tuple.tuple;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@Test
void add() throws Exception {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.add(new Bar(1, "One"), new Bar(2, "Two"), new Bar(3, "Three"));
    Assertions.assertThat(foo.getElements())
              .extracting(Bar::getId, Bar::getName)
              .containsExactly(tuple(1, "One"),
                               tuple(2, "Two"),
                               tuple(3, "Three"));
}
```

Answer (score 21):

This is a legacy answer, suitable for JUnit 4.3 and below. The modern version of JUnit includes a built-in readable failure messages in the assertThat method. Prefer other answers on this question, if possible.

```
List<E> a = resultFromTest();
List<E> expected = Arrays.asList(new E(), new E(), ...);
assertTrue("Expected 'a' and 'expected' to be equal."+
            "\n  'a'        = "+a+
            "\n  'expected' = "+expected, 
            expected.equals(a));
```

For the record, as @Paul mentioned in his comment to this answer, two `List`s are equal:

> *if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal. (Two elements `e1` and `e2` are equal if `(e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2))`.) In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the `List` interface.*

See the [JavaDocs of the `List` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: So you mean expected.equals(a) will take care of asserting the objects that the list is holding ?

Comment: From List javadoc: Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).) In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the List interface.

Comment: This alas provides less than helpful error message. I have found it better to write a utility class which performs a loop so you can see which elements are different.

Comment: @mlk, perhaps, but I'm hesitant to write a custom utility method for such a thing. What about the error message I edited just now?

Comment: @mlk I agree that it might be better to write a loop to test each element so you know exactly what is different.  It depends on what types of objects are in the list.  If they are Strings, then just say "a="+a should be fine, but if they are complex objects (other lists, or something that doesn't have a good toString implementation), it might be easier to test them individually

Comment: So in case the list are having same objects, but in different order, this expected.equals(a) will return false.

Comment: Bart/Matt - The solution I use is I have /the loop/ but if the loop finds a difference it generates a string of the array using Apache Commons ReflectionToStringBuilder for the elements. It then does a string assert on the two generated strings (as this is colour coded in Eclipses JUnit runner) followed by a simple fail should the string assert pass. It is not a solution for every occasion but it works nicely for many.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't care about the order of the elements, I recommend `ListAssert.assertEquals` in junit-addons.

Link: http://junit-addons.sourceforge.net/

For lazy Maven users:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit-addons</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-addons</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Note: If you don't care about the order of the elements, you should be using a Set or Collection, not a List.

Comment: I agree. This library is gross. Why on earth would ListAssert.assertEquals() default to orderless?

Answer (score 6):

You can use **assertEquals** in junit.

```
import org.junit.Assert;   
import org.junit.Test;

    @Test
    public void test_array_pass()
    {
        List<String> actual = Arrays.asList("fee", "fi", "foe");
        List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("fee", "fi", "foe");
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
```

If the order of elements is different then it will return error.

> If you are asserting a model object list then you should
> override the equals method in the specific model.
>
> ```
>     @Override
>     public boolean equals(Object obj) {
>         if (obj == this) {
>             return true;
>         }
>         if (obj != null && obj instanceof ModelName) {
>             ModelName other = (ModelName) obj;
>             return this.getItem().equals(other.getItem()) ;
>         }
>         return false;
>     }
> ```

Comment: The order of the parameters in Assert.assertEquals is expected result then the actual result, so in your snippet it should be 

    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);

Answer (score 4):

if you don't want to build up an array list , you can try this also

```
@Test
public void test_array_pass()
{
  List<String> list = Arrays.asList("fee", "fi", "foe");
  Strint listToString = list.toString();
  Assert.assertTrue(listToString.contains("[fee, fi, foe]"));   // passes  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Integer> figureTypes = new ArrayList<Integer>(
                           Arrays.asList(
                                 1,
                                 2
                            ));

List<Integer> figureTypes2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(
                           Arrays.asList(
                                 1,
                                 2));

assertTrue(figureTypes .equals(figureTypes2 ));
```

Comment: Can you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73898075/java-lang-assertionerror-while-checking-list-from-object-class-a-feild?

Answer (score 3):

I know there are already many options to solve this issue, but I would rather do the following to **assert two lists in any oder**:

```
assertTrue(result.containsAll(expected) && expected.containsAll(result))
```

Comment: will this not fails if the order is not matched ??

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you're interested in the equality of the contents of the list (and didn't mention order). So `containsExactlyInAnyOrder` from AssertJ is a good fit. It comes packaged with `spring-boot-starter-test`, for example.

From the [AssertJ docs ListAssert#containsExactlyInAnyOrder](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.16.1/org/assertj/core/api/ListAssert.html#containsExactlyInAnyOrder(ELEMENT...)):

> Verifies that the actual group contains exactly the given values and nothing else, in any order.
> Example:

```java
 // an Iterable is used in the example but it would also work with an array
 Iterable<Ring> elvesRings = newArrayList(vilya, nenya, narya, vilya);

 // assertion will pass
 assertThat(elvesRings).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(vilya, vilya, nenya, narya);

 // assertion will fail as vilya is contained twice in elvesRings.
 assertThat(elvesRings).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(nenya, vilya, narya);
```

Answer (score 0):

`assertEquals(expected, result);` works for me.
Since this function gets two objects, you can pass anything to it.

```java
public static void assertEquals(Object expected, Object actual) {
    AssertEquals.assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no duplicates, following code should do the job

```
    Assertions.assertTrue(firstList.size() == secondList.size() 
        && firstList.containsAll(secondList) 
        && secondList.containsAll(firstList));
```

**Note**: In case of duplicates, assertion will pass if number of elements is the same in both lists (even if different elements are duplicated in each list.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the below code, it'll help in your case and import the following Assertions package - `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;`

```
Assertions.assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't this the all the above answers are giving the exact solution for comparing two lists of Objects.
Most of above approaches can be helpful in following limit of comparisons only
- Size comparison
- Reference comparison

But if we have same sized lists of objects and different data on the objects level then this comparison approaches won't help.

I think the following approach will work perfectly with overriding equals and hashcode method on the user-defined object.

I used [Xstream](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream/1.4.10) lib for override equals and hashcode but we can override equals and hashcode by out won logics/comparison too.

Here is the example for your reference

```
    import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    class TestClass {
      private String name;
      private String id;

      public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
      }

      public String getName() {
        return this.name;
      }

      public String getId() {
        return id;
      }

      public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
      }

      /**
       * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
       */
      @Override
      public boolean equals(Object o) {
        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        String oxml = xstream.toXML(o);
        String myxml = xstream.toXML(this);

        return myxml.equals(oxml);
      }

      /**
       * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
       */
      @Override
      public int hashCode() {
        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        String myxml = xstream.toXML(this);
        return myxml.hashCode();
      }
    }

    public class XstreamCompareTest {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
      checkObjectEquals();
}

      private static void checkObjectEquals() {
        List<TestClass> testList1 = new ArrayList<TestClass>();
        TestClass tObj1 = new TestClass();
        tObj1.setId("test3");
        tObj1.setName("testname3");
        testList1.add(tObj1);

        TestClass tObj2 = new TestClass();
        tObj2.setId("test2");
        tObj2.setName("testname2");
        testList1.add(tObj2);

        testList1.sort((TestClass t1, TestClass t2) -> t1.getId().compareTo(t2.getId()));

        List<TestClass> testList2 = new ArrayList<TestClass>();
        TestClass tObj3 = new TestClass();
        tObj3.setId("test3");
        tObj3.setName("testname3");
        testList2.add(tObj3);

        TestClass tObj4 = new TestClass();
        tObj4.setId("test2");
        tObj4.setName("testname2");
        testList2.add(tObj4);

        testList2.sort((TestClass t1, TestClass t2) -> t1.getId().compareTo(t2.getId()));

        if (isNotMatch(testList1, testList2)) {
          System.out.println("The list are not matched");
        } else {
          System.out.println("The list are matched");
        }

      }

      private static boolean isNotMatch(List<TestClass> clist1, List<TestClass> clist2) {
        return clist1.size() != clist2.size() || !clist1.equals(clist2);
      }
    }
```

The most important thing is that you can ignore the fields by Annotation (@XStreamOmitField) if you don't want to include any fields on the equal check of Objects. There are many Annotations like this to configure so have a look deep about the annotations of this lib.

I am sure this answer will save your time to identify the correct approach for comparing two lists of objects :). Please comment if you see any issues on this.