# compare two list of objects in Java to remove duplicate

Tags: java

I have two list of Objects. I have framed this list by querying the database.

For Ex:

```
List<Employee> firstList={holDate,holName,createdby,empId}
List<Employee> seconList={holDate,holName,createdby,empId}
```

Now, I need to compare `holDate`, `holName` of `firstList` with `holDate`, `holName` of `secondList`. If `holDate`, `holName` of `firstList` not found in `secondList`, I need to add that in separate list.

The list may be in any order.

**NOTE: empId is a primary key column.**

Update - what I've tried:

```java
for(Employee emp:firstList) { 
    for(Employee tgtEmp:seconList) {  
        if((emp.getHolDate()!=tgtEmp.getHolDate())&& (emp.getHolName()!=tgtEmp.getHolName())){ 
            printList.add(emp); break; 
        } 
    }
}
```

Sample List Values:

firstList={{2015-08-15,"Independence Day","e1","Empl"},{2015-01-26,"Republic Day","e1","Empl"},{2015-09-20,"Memorial Day","e1","Empl"}} 
seconList={{2015-08-15,"Independence Day","e1","Emp2"},{2015-10-25,"Thanks Giving Day","e1","Emp2"}}

Here, newlist should have all the values which is available in seconList and "RepublicDay","MemorialDay" from firstList

Comment: What is `Employee`?  Does it have a custom `equals` and `hashcode` method, cause it would really easy then to just use `List#removeAll` or `List#retainAll` to identify the duplicates.  Of course, you could just both of them into some kind of `Set`...

Comment: You did any research before asking question? See plenty of question you can get in stackoverflow

Comment: Hi Renjith, pls find below snippet<br>  for(Employee emp:firstList){
    
    for(Employee tgtEmp:seconList){
     
     if((emp.getHolDate()!=tgtEmp.getHolDate())&&
       (emp.getHolName()!=tgtEmp.getHolName())){
      printList.add(emp);
      break;
     }        
    } 
   }

Comment: Why not do this at the db during extraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```
 for (Employee emp : firstList) {
        boolean found=false;
        for (Employee tgtEmp : seconList) {
            if ((emp.getHolDate().equals(tgtEmp.getHolDate())) && (emp.getHolName().equals(tgtEmp.getHolName()))) {
                found=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found){
            printList.add(emp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is that okay to use this method if the size of list is very large? what will be the performance?

Comment: @Codingworld you can use Objects.equals aswell

Answer (score 0):

I think the above answer is not generically. Think if you add any new field on the Emp object then you need to update the equals method. If you are open to accepting new solution then please consider the below answer

[Assert List in Junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236880/assert-list-in-junit/49064684#49064684)