# How to assert that lists are equal with testng?

Tags: java, testng

I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10660606) for junit, but need a solution for testng. Any ideas more usefull as writing an own for loop?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's no need for a separate method for `List` comparison. Two lists can be compared by `org.testng.Assert#assertEquals(Object, Object)`.

If two lists `a` and `b` are non-`null`, the call `Assert.assertEquals(a, b)` means `a.equals(b)` will be called subsequently.

And `java.util.List#equals` is what you need, as described in javadoc:

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns
>   true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists
>   have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two
>   lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if (e1==null ?
>   e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).) In other words, two lists are defined to
>   be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This
>   definition ensures that the equals method works properly across
>   different implementations of the List interface.

Comment: Have to check that, but sounds correct. Is there a difference for assertEquals between JUnit and testng?

Comment: In fact, it depends: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/pull/790 but it should work most of the time.

Comment: Just a small note, shouldn't this be order dependent for both the lists?