# Comparing two list of objects in Java

Tags: java, list, list-comparison

I have two list of Student Objects(listA & listB) which were formed by querying from two different databases. I need to iterate one list and need to make sure it is not present in the other list.

I have used the below comparison code for the same i.e overwritten the equals method and compared using for loops.

Say List A & List B could have 5000 rows each, can you suggest if there are better ways to implement this?

**Comparison code:**

```
for (Student dataA:listA) {
    for (Student dataB:listB) {
        if(dataB.equals(dataA))
            break;                                              
    }
}
```

**Student Object:**

```
public class Student {
    int A;
    int B;
    String C;   

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Student student = (Student) obj;
        return A == student.A && B == student.B && C.equals(student.C);
    }
}
```

Edit Note: ListA & ListB can have different number of rows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Compare Two Lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762093/java-compare-two-lists)

Comment: The perfect answer to this question :) [Save your time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236880/assert-about-a-list-in-junit/49064684#49064684)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you the `retainAll` method:

```
List<Student> listC = new ArrayList();
listC.addAll(listA);
listC.retainAll(listB);   //now listC contains all double students
```

But you should still override the `equals` method

Comment: I actually need the inverse. I need the ones that are not present in the other list.

Comment: then use `removeAll()` instead of `retainAll` :-)

Comment: Sorry I got confused and confused you too.. Anyways I understood your point :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `containsAny` method from `CollectionUtils` (Apache Commons):

```
if(CollectionUtils.containsAny(listA, listB)){
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The general approach is iterate through first list and check for element if it is contained in second list, if it exist add the element to the result list
Below is the complete solution

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CompareListofObj {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Student> listStd1 = new ArrayList<Student>();
    List<Student> listStd2 = new ArrayList<Student>();

    Student std1 = new Student(1, 1, "a");
    Student std2 = new Student(2, 1, "b");
    Student std3 = new Student(3, 3, "c");
    Student std4 = new Student(4, 4, "d");
    listStd1.add(std1);
    listStd1.add(std2);
    listStd1.add(std3);
    listStd1.add(std4);

    Student std5 = new Student(1, 1, "a");
    Student std6 = new Student(2, 1, "b");
    Student std7 = new Student(7, 7, "c");
    Student std8 = new Student(8, 8, "d");
    listStd2.add(std5);
    listStd2.add(std6);
    listStd2.add(std7);
    listStd2.add(std8);

    List<Student> listResult = new ArrayList<Student>();

    for (int i = 0; i < listStd1.size(); i++) {
        if (listStd2.contains(listStd1.get(i))) {

            listResult.add(listStd1.get(i));

        } else {

        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < listResult.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("common elt" + listResult.get(i).getA() + ", " + listResult.get(i).getB() + ", "
                + listResult.get(i).getC());
    }

}
}
```

Student class

```
package sample;

public class Student {

int A;
int B;
String C;

public Student(int a, int b, String c) {
    super();
    A = a;
    B = b;
    C = c;
}

public int getA() {
    return A;
}

public void setA(int a) {
    A = a;
}

public int getB() {
    return B;
}

public void setB(int b) {
    B = b;
}

public String getC() {
    return C;
}

public void setC(String c) {
    C = c;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + A;
    result = prime * result + B;
    result = prime * result + ((C == null) ? 0 : C.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Student other = (Student) obj;
    if (A != other.A)
        return false;
    if (B != other.B)
        return false;
    if (C == null) {
        if (other.C != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!C.equals(other.C))
        return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: It's nice that you included code. Could you tell us a little about it? What is your general approach here?

Comment: The general approach is iterate through first list and check for element if it is contained in second list, if it exist add the element to the result list.

Comment: Awesome. It would be helpful to edit your answer to include that information. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I did.

Answer (score 0):

The removeAll command is the way to go, but List lookup is not efficient (linear time), so you get a O(n*m) total time (n is sizeA, m is sizeB); 5000 entries on each, it may be a bit too much.

If possible, you should change it to use Sets (and implements the hashCode and equals methods of your Student classes in case you didn't already!):

```
Set<Student> studentsA = new HashSet<>();
Set<Student> studentsB = new HashSet<>();
studentsA.removeAll(studentsB);
```

This gets you O(m*hash(n)).