# How do I compare my response with the new Employee?

Tags: java, json, rest, http, testng

Checkout my screenshot:

[image: screenshot depicting AssertionError]

```
@Test
public void getAllEmployeesTest() throws IOException {
    HttpResponse response = http.get("http://localhost:8087/employee");
    List<Employee> expectedList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    expectedList.add(new Employee(2, "Yashwant", "Chavan", 30, true));
    List<Employee> actualList = gson.fromJson(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()), new ArrayList<Employee>().getClass());
    Assert.assertEquals(actualList, expectedList);
}
```

Comment: Hi! I edited your question to display the image. It would be better if you included the text of the error in the question rather than using screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

If the `Employee` class does not implement the `equals` method, then `Object` equals method is used. Object `equals` method will return true iff both the objects are equal.

If you do not want to implement `equals` method, you can use the `ReflectionAssert.assertReflectionEquals` (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.unitils/unitils-core/3.4.6) which compares the fields in the two objects via reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell us more about what you expect to see and what you're actually seeing. However, I'll take a guess that `Assert.assertEquals(actualList, expectedList);` fails. I assume too that your employee endpoint is supposed to return that one matching employee...

So, does your Employee class implement `equals(Object other)` sensibly? If so, you should be able to do as you're doing. If not, make it so and try again.

See also [Assert about a List in Junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236880/assert-about-a-list-in-junit)

Comment: i get a jsonformat output in my actual, maybe thats why?

Comment: Er, yes. The screenshot (which I can now see) makes that clear.

Comment: I asked the OP for more clarification. It's obvious to me that his actual and expected differ. I see plenty of comments along the lines of "SO is not a homework factory" so I am leaving this as it is.

Answer (score 0):

1. As others said, make sure your `Employee` class implements a reasonable `equals()`. If it's just a plain POJO, `equals` generated
2. The correct use of [`assertEquals()`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.8/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) is `assertEquals(expected, actual)`. Use it that to have the `equals()` method of the expected object to be invoked (rather than the other way around, which may or may not be a problem).
3. Refer to this question for a way to deserialize a List with Gson: [Google Gson - deserialize list<class> object? (generic type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554217/google-gson-deserialize-listclass-object-generic-type)