# How to use assertThat Contains any order method for list comparison in Junit (java)

Tags: java, junit, assertion

I want to test `ShipmentEntityBO` method using `assertThat & Contains` any order. The below test function is not working since list has returned the object. Please advise me.

```
public class ShipmentEntityBO {
    public void addShipmentEntityToList(List<ShipmentEntity> shipmentEntityList,String shipmentDetails) {
        String splited[] = shipmentDetails.split(",");
        shipmentEntityList.add(new ShipmentEntity(new Integer(splited[0]), splited[1],
                    splited[2], new Long(splited[3]), splited[4]));
    }
}
```

**Junit code**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsCollectionWithSize.hasSize;
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.containsInAnyOrder;
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableContainingInOrder.contains;

public class Junit {

    ShipmentEntityBO shipmentEntityBO;

    @Before
    public void createObjectForShipmentEntity() {
        shipmentEntityBO = new ShipmentEntityBO();  
    }

    @Test
    public void testListofShipmentEntity() {
        ArrayList<ShipmentEntity> list = new ArrayList<ShipmentEntity>();
        String details = "101,pavi,12345,8500,Toronto";
        shipmentEntityBO.addShipmentEntityToList(list, details);
        assertThat(list,containsInAnyOrder("Toronto","pavi",101,"12345",8500)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code of *containsInAnyOrder* method?

Comment: Can you show us the constructor of `ShipmentEntity`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assert about a List in Junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236880/assert-about-a-list-in-junit)

Answer (score 1):

The following code ...

```
String details = "101,pavi,12345,8500,Toronto";
addShipmentEntityToList(list, details);
```

... populates the given `list` with **1** entry which is of type `ShippingEntry` and has been populated from the given `details`

However your assertion attempts to verify that the `list` contains **5** entries none of which are of type `ShipmentEntity` i.e. `"Toronto","pavi",101,"12345",8500` so that assertion fails.

It is possible that the following assertion will pass:

```
assertThat(list,containsInAnyOrder(new ShipmentEntity(101, "pavi", "12345", 8500L, "Toronto")));
```

However, without seeing the constructor and the `equals()` method of `ShipmentEntity` I cannot be certain of that. And, without knowing what you are *trying* to do it is difficult to know what the correct fix is.

If the above does not work for you then please:

1. Describe exactly what you are trying to do i.e. describe the purpose of your test.
2. Update your question to include the constructor and the `equals()` method of `ShipmentEntity`